# Configuring ASP.NET 1.1 application on IIS 7.5 window 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-1.1

I deployed asp.net 1.1 applications (vs2003) on window 2008 R2 at IIS 7.5.

While browsing default page it is giving httphandle of errors.

I want to know if an asp.net 1.1 application is compatible with IIS 7.5 or is

Comment: Check you application pool .net version.

Comment: it showing classic ,2.2 but i could not find 1.1 . it working fine on iis6 .

Comment: is  there compartibilty issue with asp.net 1.1 and iis 7.5.

Comment: This may help you http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

Comment: Your final sentence is incomplete. Could you please read over your question and make sure it makes sense?